# In vs. Comparison Search Conditions

Tags: t-sql

I understand that `WHERE 1 = '1'` returns true, and also `WHERE 222 = CONVERT(varchar, 222)` will return true in T-SQL.

But, when working with IN, can the test_expression and the subquery be of different datatypes? For example can the test_expression be an int, and the subquery varchar?

Comment: If this is a prelude to *yet another question* about why SQL doesn't magically interpret `'1,2,3'` as 3 separate values in an IN clause, I'm going to be unhappy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can be: all datatypes will be cast to the highest based on "[datatype precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)" rules.

Logically, `x in (a,b,c)` is actually `x=a or x=b or x=c` of course. This is relevant for this contrived case using scalar values. I *really don't know* if all values are CAST to float (the highest here) before comparison (`..IN..`) or cast per comparison (`..OR..OR..`)

```
WHERE
  CAST(1 AS int) IN ('1', CAST(1.0 AS float), 1.0 /*decimal*/)
```

For a subquery in the IN clause, then the *column* has a data type that will be CAST as per the scalar rules

Edit, after comment:

All datatypes will be implicitly CAST

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM sys.columns
WHERE
    1 IN (SELECT CAST('1' AS CHAR(1)) FROM sys.columns)
```

or

```
DECLARE @intvar int = 1, @charvar char(1) = '1';

SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM sys.columns
WHERE
    @intvar IN (SELECT @charvar FROM sys.columns)
```

Comment: Looking at this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177682.aspx, how should one interpret the sentence: "This column must have the same data type as test_expression."